# emacsclient complains about files are not saved when I try to close it

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

I'm running emacs in daemon mode and usually have multiple instances of emacsclient open. Whenever I close down one of the client instances (with `C-x C-c` or `save-buffers-kill-terminal`) I am prompted to save all of the files currently open, not realizing that they'll remain open on other client. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: how do you "close down one of them"? what is your `server-done-hook`?

Comment: @sds I updated my answer with a clarification. The command is C-x C-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you observe is the correct documented behavior of [`save-buffers-kill-terminal`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Exiting.html).

What you need to use instead is <kbd>C-x #</kbd> ([`server-edit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html)).